# Threejs texture (creating stargate!)

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I've been messing around with shaders (fresnel etc) and I was wondering if there were any examples out there about how to create a stargate-like texture (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jglGjkSoqXA when it's flat!). Something that is a like reflective water? I'm not sure how to go about this!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Google?  [Here a whole project on GIThub](http://jeremybouny.fr/ocean/demo/)